# Are dropped alien items automatically picked up at the end of a mission?

Tags: xcom-2

If one of the aliens, e.g. a sectoid, drops an item when it is killed but I complete the mission before picking it up - do I still get whatever the item is?  Or is it lost forever?

You do seem to collect some stuff after a mission, but I haven't been able to see if that includes drop items like weapon mods etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you will.  Any items dropped upon mission success is immediately picked up.  I've gotten dropped items that turned out to be weapon mods despite not picking them up.

Comment: Tested and confirmed this.

Comment: It's also one of the loading tips.

Comment: The loading tip also states you won't get it for an evacuation.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is stated as one of the loading tips:

[image: Loading tip image]